# Font media queries not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to make some text responsive. For some reason, media queries are not working and the font is pushed below the image, whereas it should be above.
Here is my code:

```js
// Bootstrap callback test
if ($('#bootstrapCssTest').is(':visible') === true) {
  $('<link href="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').appendTo('head');
}

// Make .navbarButtonDiv go to its child 'a' tag's href on click
$(".navbarButtonDiv").click(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  return false;
});

// Collapse navbar on nav link click
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-collapse.in', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('a')) {
    $(this).collapse('hide');
  }
});

// Collapse navbar on document click
$(document).on('click', function() {
  $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```css
/* Font imports */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,400italic,700);
@font-face {
  font-family: "FuturaNewLight";
  src: url("fonts/FuturaNewLight.otf")
}
/* Navbar padding */

body {
  padding-top: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
/* Navbar */

.navbar {
  font-family: "Bitter", serif;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom > .wrapper .navbar-brand.navbar-brand-centered {
  margin-left: -55px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.navbar .nav.navbar-nav {
  font-size: 150%;
}
.navbar-logo {
  height: 145%;
}
/* Media queries */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .wrapper {
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    line-height: 60px;
    transition: background 200ms linear;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background: #96D5FF;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom {
    padding: 20px 0;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
    margin: 20px 0 -20px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 260px;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-logo {
    margin-left: 20px;
    height: 110%;
  }
  .futuraNewLightHeader {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
/* Header styling */

#jumbotronHeader {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Bitter", serif;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 9px;
}
#homePageImage {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 70%;
}
/* Font styling */

.futuraNewLightHeader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 550px;
  font-size: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  color: White;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px Black;
  font-family: "FuturaNewLight";
}
.futuraNewLightSubHeader {
  position: absolute;
  top: 750px;
  font-size: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  color: White;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px Black;
  font-family: "FuturaNewLight";
}
#dynamicHeaderText {
  color: #2099FF;
}
/* General styling */

.centerText {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Education for Everyone</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/edufeLogo.png">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom" role="navigation">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-centered" href="#/">
          <img class="navbar-logo" src="images/edufeLogo.png">
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Learn</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Log In</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Jumbotron -->
    <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotronHeader">
      <h1 class="display-3 centerText">Education for Everyone</h1>
      <p class="lead centerText">Learn. Create. Share.</p>
      <hr class="m-y-3">
    </div>

    <!-- Image header -->
    <div class="imageHeader">
      <span class="futuraNewLightHeader centerText"><span id="dynamicHeaderText">Learn</span> something new.</span>
      <span class="futuraNewLightSubHeader centerText">From the internet to real life.</span>
    </div>

    <img src="images/homePageImage.png" id="homePageImage" class="center-block img-responsive">
  </div>

  <!-- Script tags -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks! Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Move all text formatting options into the media queries and try then.

Answer (score 0):

First you need set @media queries to @media screen and (max-width: ....). 
Some cases browsers need screen parameter.

Second, you need change font size of elements when responsive. I suggest using em unit to make responsive.